# Obtain user access with a Windows service?

Tags: winapi, windows-services

I have a service application. In this service, I would like to access values stored under the `CURRENT_USER` section for my user in the registry. It appears to me the way to go about this is to associate the service to the current user account, I understand the service runs with `SYSTEM` user access by default.

I've found the service logon tab under Service Properties in the Windows Service Manager, so I'm pretty sure there's an API somewhere that does what I want. How do I associate a service to my user in the code?

Comment: You associate the service with a user account when you register the service, via the lpServiceStartName parameter of CreateService(). Once registered, there is no API to change the user, it can only be done in the SCM UI.

Comment: @Remy, you can use ChangeServiceConfig().

Comment: But the OP would probably be better off biting the bullet and moving the settings to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I forgot about that. But you can't change the user account with it while the service is running, the change won't take effect until the service is restarted.

Comment: @Remy, lpServiceStartName was exactly what I was looking for when posting the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your analysis of what you need to do is not at all aligned with the reality of multi-user systems.

Consider the scenario where a machine has two regular users, A and B. User A uses the machine in the morning, and then logs out. User B logs in after lunch and uses the machine for the rest of the day. When you set up the logon details for a service you have to specify a single user for the service. But which user do you pick, A or B?

And it gets worse. The scenario above has a single user logged on at any one time. But it's perfectly possible for multiple users to be logged on to the machine at the same time. Which one do you want? Presumably the active one. But then what if the machine is running terminal services and multiple users are active at once?

Neglecting the terminal services issue, and just considering the first scenario, you could do the following:

1. Find the active session, and find the user associated with that session.
2. Find that user's SID.
3. Read the appropriate hive for that SID from `HKEY_USERS`.

However, I wonder if this is really what you are hoping to do. My guess is that there is a better solution to your problem, whatever your problem happens to be. But I would not want to speculate on what that better solution is without knowing what the problem is.

Finally, the `SYSTEM` account is the most powerful account on the machine. For security reasons, you are advised not to run your service under that account unless there is a very good reason to do so. Do you really need to use this account?

Comment: The problem: The service runs on a number of dedicated hosts in order to handle performance-heavy computation tasks. The software to process these tasks is protected by a license. The licenses are stored in the registry at user-level in order to associate each license key with a user. I've been unable to access the license keys in this part of the registry from the service, rendering me unable to launch the processing software.

Comment: A solution we've discussed is to associate the service to a dedicated user, leading to my question here. I'm not happy about this solution myself, so I am very interested in suggestions for better answers to my problem

Comment: Instead of accessing HKEY_USERS directly, have the service find the desired user's session, get its user token and impersonate that user, and then use RegOpenCurrentUser() to open that user's HKEY_CURRENT_USER hive. Or, once you have the user token, use CreateProcessAsUser() to run a process in the user's session, and then have that process access HKEY_CURRENT_USER and send the data back to the service as needed.

Comment: This works, thanks a lot. I've made a small class to expand TRegistry with the functionality, I will post it somewhere here on SO. there is a good chance it will help others who have been looking for examples on how it is done.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, to start with, I'd recommend to go through some articles on MSDN on Windows services programming. Articles by Solomon & Russinovich are a good start.

First thing -- services are supposed to be "unattended". If you want a service to interact anyhow with users, there are couple of ways:

- Run service under specific user credentials
- Create runnable-by-user UI

Methods have pros and cons. Running under specific user credentials means a bit of administering work. It can be easy in some scenarios and it can be too painful in some corporate newtorks.
User application is another way. Think of any, say DB admin console that you have in icon tray. That's it. DB runs as a service, and you have user app. This is a bit extra work, but on the other hand you have way better separation between service functionality and actual control over this functionality, potentially per-user in multi-user environment.